# Let $X$ be a$KC$ space. Then $X^{*}$ is $KC$ iff $X$ is a $K$ -space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

**The bellow theorem exist in " Between $T_{1} $ and $T_{2}$ " by " Albert Wilansky ."**

Let $ (‎ ‎X‎^{*},‎\tau‎^{*} ‎)‎ $ be topological space one- point compatification of $ ( X. \tau)$. A 
topological space is called $k$ - space if it has the property that  any subset $S$ such that $ S\cap K$ is closed for all closed compact $K$ is itself closed.

*** Theorem : Let $X$ be a$KC$ space. Then $X^{*}$ is  $KC$   iff $X$  is a $K$ -space*.**

**Proof:** Let $X$ be a $K$ space .Let $S$ be a $\tau^{*}$- compact subset of  $X^{*}$ . If $ S\subset X$, is $\tau$- compact , hence $\tau$-closed, thus $\tau^{*}$-closed. If on the other hand $\infty‎ \in S$, let $ F = S - \{\infty‎  \}$ . Now let $K$ be an ar bitray $\tau $-closed compact subset of $X$ . Then $K$ is  $\tau^{*}$- closed. and so $ S \cap K$ is$\tau^{*}$-compact: hence $\tau $- compact, since it is a subset of $S$ . since $X$ is a $KC$ space,$ S \cap K$ is $\tau $-closed, and so $ S \cap K = F \cap K$ is  $\tau $-closed. since $X$ is $K$ space it follow that $F$ is $\tau $-closed.Then $S$ is $\tau^{*}$-closed because $X^{*} - S = X - F$ is $ \tau$- open, hence $\tau^{*}$-open.

Conversly, let $X^{*}$ be $KC$. Let $F$ be a subset of $X$ which obeys the test condition, namely $F \cap K$  is closed for every closed compact compact set $ K \subset X $. Let $S = F \cup \{ \infty‎  \}$. Let $ ‎\Omega‎$ be a covering  of $S$ by $\tau^{*}$-open sets. Choose $ G \in \Omega‎$  whith $\infty‎  \in  \Omega‎$. Now $X - S$ is   $\tau^{*}$- closed, i.e. closed and compact: thus it meets $F$ in a closed(hence compact) set, i.e . $F - G $ is $\tau$-compact;  Let $\Omega^{\prime}‎ = \{  O- \infty‎   : O \in \Omega \} $;  then  $\Omega^{\prime}‎$ is an open cover of $ F - G $. Reducing $\Omega^{\prime}‎ $ to a finite cover  of $ F- G $ , restoring $ \infty‎  $ to  each  of its members and adjoining $G$  gives a covering of $S$ which  is a finite subcover of $\Omega$. We  have now proved that $S$ is $\tau^{*}$-compact. By hypothesise if  follow that $s$ is   $\tau^{*}$-closed. But  $ F = S \cap X $; thus $F$ is $\tau$-closed. it folow that $X$ is a $K$- space.

> (1): In the first paragraph, why  we can say $ S \cap K = F \cap K$? and $X^{*} - S = X - F$
>
> (2)
>   In the second paragraph, why  " $X - S$ is   $\tau^{*}$- closed, i.e. closed and compact?and $F - G $ is $\tau$-compact"  ?
>
> (3)Why is it true that  " $\Omega^{\prime}‎$ is an open cover of $ F - G $. Reducing $\Omega^{\prime}‎ $ to a finite cover  of $ F- G $ , restoring $ \infty‎  $ to  each  of its members and adjoining $G$  gives a covering of $S$ which  is a finite subcover of $\Omega$" ?

Answer (score 1):

1. $F=S\setminus\{\infty\}$, so $F\cap K=(S\setminus\{\infty\})\cap K=(S\cap K)\setminus\{\infty\}$. But $K\subseteq X$, so $\infty\notin K$, and therefore $(S\cap K)\setminus\{\infty\}=S\cap K$. $X^*\setminus S=(X\cup\{\infty\})\setminus(F\cup\{\infty\})=X\setminus F$.
2. It should read: *Choose* $G\in\Omega$ *with* $\infty\in G$. *Now* $X\setminus G$ *is* $\tau^*$-*closed, i.e., closed and compact.* This is trivial: $G$ is an open nbhd of $\infty$ in $X^*$, so of course $X\setminus G=X^*\setminus G$ is $\tau^*$-closed, and since $X^*$ is compact, this implies that $X\setminus G$ is $\tau^*$-compact as well. The topologies $\tau$ and $\tau^*$ agree on $X$, and $X\setminus G\subseteq X$, so $X\setminus G$ is $\tau$-compact and $\tau$-closed. Let $K=X\setminus G$; then $K$ is a compact, closed subset of $X$, so by hypothesis $F\cap K$ is $\tau$-closed. And $$F\cap K=F\cap(X\setminus G)=F\setminus G\;,$$ so $F\setminus G$ is $\tau$-closed. But then $F\setminus G$ is a $\tau$-closed subset of the $\tau$-compact set $X\setminus G$, so $F\setminus G$ is $\tau$-compact.
3. I suspect that you miscopied the definition of $\Omega'$: I suspect that it should be $$\Omega'=\big\{O\setminus\{\infty\}:O\in\Omega\setminus\{G\}\big\}\;.$$ $\Omega$ covers $S$, so $\Omega\setminus\{G\}$ covers $S\setminus G=(F\setminus G)\cup\{\infty\}$, and it's now clear that $\Omega'$ covers $F\setminus G$ and is $\tau$-open. $F\setminus G$ is $\tau$-compact, so some finite subset $\Omega''$ of $\Omega'$ covers $F\setminus G$. For each $U\in\Omega''$ there is an $O_U\in\Omega$ such that $U=O_U\setminus\{\infty\}$; then $\{O_U:U\in\Omega''\}\cup\{G\}$ is a finite subset of $\Omega$ that covers $S$. For if $x\in F\setminus G$, then $x\in U\subseteq O_U$ for some $U\in\Omega''$, and if $x\in S\cap G$, then $x\in G$. (Note that $\infty\in S\cap G$, so it does get covered.)